# Why does adding a color attachment cause a 3x slowdown?

Tags: c++, opengl, framebuffer, fbo

i was rendering some models depth-only like this:

```
m_fbo = new globjects::Framebuffer();
depthBuffer = globjects::Texture::createDefault();
depthBuffer->storage2D(1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, size, size);
m_fbo->attachTexture(GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, depthBuffer);

m_fbo->bind();
... draw all the things
```

now, when i added a color attachment to it like this:

```
m_fbo = new globjects::Framebuffer();
depthBuffer = globjects::Texture::createDefault();
depthBuffer->storage2D(1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, size, size);
m_fbo->attachTexture(GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, depthBuffer);

attributeBuffer = globjects::Texture::createDefault();
attributeBuffer->storage2D(1, <format>, size, size);
m_fbo->attachTexture(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, attributeBuffer);

m_fbo->bind();
... draw all the things
```

depending on the format of the attribute buffer, rendering time went from 2.6ms to 5ms (R8, RG8), 8.5ms (RGB8, RGBA8, R32F) or 14.5ms (RG32F, RGBA32F) (measured with opengl timer queries).

I didn't even change the fragment shader, so i don't calculate any additional values to write into that color buffer. rendering time goes down again if i comment out that `attachTexture` line.

the texture at hand is a 2Kx2K shadowmap atlas. the program i use tessellates the models, converts each triangle to a point and renders that point with gl_PointSize = 1 into one randomly chosen 64x64 tile inside that atlas. tesselation and geometry shader are quite heavy so i don't think this is this is bandwidth or fillrate bound. this slowdown is much smaller (1.9 to 2.1ms) if i render into one large shadowmap instead of multiple small ones.

if i manually write the attributes into a texture with imageStore in the geometry shader and don't use a color attachment, the slowdown is reasonable as well (1.9 to 2.3ms)

also, this slowdown mysteriously disappears when i start tracing with nsight, which makes it impossible to profile this.

any ideas why this might happen?

I'm using a 750 Ti.

Answer (score 1):

Like most OpenGL performance issues, they are implementation dependent. Therefore we can only guess, unless we know how the actual implementation works.

1. GPUs are usually optimized for depth-only rendering. Since you're adding a color attachment, you're not doing depth-only rendering anymore.
2. Your color attachment format is `GL_R32F`. This format is most likely slower to render to than a regular old `GL_RGBA8` format.
3. If you change render targets every time you switch to a randomly chosen 64x64 shadowmap, this is really slow. Changing a render target is a very costly operation, but there are some ways around it. See page 29 of this presentation: http://http.download.nvidia.com/developer/presentations/2005/GDC/OpenGL_Day/OpenGL_FrameBuffer_Object.pdf
4. If I understood you correctly, you're rendering lots of 1 pixel triangles. This is very slow. This is because GPUs rasterize pixels in groups of 2x2 pixels. Even if only one pixel gets rendered, the hardware will still run the shader 4 times and then just discard 3 pixels. If all you're rendering are 1 pixel triangles, then you're effectively wasting a 3/4 of your rasterization performance.

May I ask why you're using the depth attachment format `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F`? Most GPUs don't even support 32 bit depth buffers. Usually 24 bits. Did you try using `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24` or `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32` instead?

This is a very peculiar problem though. Did you try updating your GPU drivers?

Comment: 1: sure, and i did expect a performance hit, but not one this large. 2: i tried other formats, they don't have any effect. 3: all shadowmaps are in this one large atlas, no switching involved. 4: i'm rendering points and setting gl_pointSize to one. the point about wasting rasterization performance might still be true, but this also was the case without the color attachment :) 5. no special reason. i'll try 24bits, but i doubt it will affect the color buffer problem...?

Comment: The depth buffer hint was just a general hint. This seems to be a very weird issue. Are you sure you're measuring the performance correctly? How are you rendering to only a region of the shadow map? By changing the viewport?

Comment: i was wrong about the format thing, it does make a huge difference depending on how many bytes it occupies, see question. Depth buffer format does indeed make no difference. I had no reason to doubt the measurements so far, i'm using GL_TIME_ELAPSED queries around the drawing commands. Rendering to a region: I have an array of projection matrices and choose and apply one of them in the geom shader, and then scale and bias into the respective tile. Also note the addition to question, manually imageStoring the attributes into a new buffer is significantly faster than the attachment...

Comment: @Karyon: Of course it makes a huge difference, as it affects bandwith. The reason why you're not seeing a difference when changing the depth buffer format is most likely because it falls back to a certain format no matter what you specify. "and then scale and bias into the respective tile" Are your tiles all on a single texture or separate textures?

Comment: That's really confusing. In your question you state you tried rendering into multiple small tiles vs one large shadow map. Do you mean you treated the whole shadow map as a single tile? Is the distribution less random if you render to a single tile? One problem I can think of resulting from your "randomized" approach is: Cache misses. Lots of cache misses. This can cause severe performance drops.

Comment: exactly that, 1k small tiles in one 2k texture vs one large tile in the same 2k texture. i also thought about cache misses, but 1st this should also happen when rendering depth-only and 2nd this should definitely happen when doing imageStores instead of the second render target.

Comment: The more FBO attachments you add, the more cache misses you're gonna get, because there's more data involved.